# How can I add google map to my web site

Tags: asp.net

How can I add google map to my web site using Visual Studio C# ? Please answer step by step. Thans a lot

Answer (score 1):

You will need an API key provided by Google so that usage quotas can be monitored. Begin by reading through some of the usage rules and applying for the key here: 
http://www.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

You'll need to confirm registration by clicking on link provided by you via email, at which time the API key will be provided to you. Paste this key into a text file, as you'll need to integrate it into the scripts used to create the maps.

Check this link
http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/3528381/Integrating-Google-Maps-into-Your-Web-Applications.htm

Comment: An API key is no longer required in V3.